# jQuery displaying 'stacked images' in photoshop

Tags: jquery, photoshop

Is there a way to stack images into 1 'set', in PHOTOSHOP in such a way that you can then apply some jQuery or javascript to that image to display each stacked image when you click on it.

I am writing a program which as 150 folders each containing 5 images, and I want to display them as a stack that goes through each of the 5 images of a set. Then you click on 'next' and folder 2 is loaded up and you can click on the image to go through that set of 5 and so on...

OK I need to be more specific. Here is my index page:

```
 <html>
 <head>
<title>index</title>
 </head>
 <body>

 <img src="1.jpg" id="displayimage" alt="" onmousedown="change()">

  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
 imgs=Array("1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg", "5.jpg", "6.jpg", "7.jpg", "8.jpg",   "9.jpg", "10.jpg", "11.jpg", "12.jpg", "13.jpg", "14.jpg", "15.jpg", "16.jpg", "17.jpg", "18.jpg", "19.jpg", "20.jpg", "21.jpg", "22.jpg", "23.jpg", "24.jpg");
 var x=0;

 function change() {
 document.getElementById("displayimage").setAttribute("src", imgs[++x]);

if (x==23) {
x=0;
 }
 }
```

This does what i want, if you click on the image the next image appears.

The problem is i need to make the src dynamic. This works fine with all the images in tha same directory as the index page, but i have 50 folders named images1, images2, images3 ..... and in each folder there is 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg etc etc. Is there a way to make to change the src in the JS to an extension images1/imgs[++x] and also, is there then a way to make the '1' dynamic

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can. But you could place all images next to each other and just use parts of the image with `background-image`. Although there is a JavaScript PSD parser here http://www.webappers.com/2012/02/02/a-photoshop-psd-file-parser-in-javascript/

Comment: Do you have screenshot of what you want to do. It is a little bit unclear. What does "Is there a way to stack images into 1 'set'" truly mean.

Comment: Any good news from your side?

Answer (score 0):

Before stacking your images you should pass from your program the width of each image eg:

folder1/galleryData.txt:

```
img1.jpg|340
img2.jpg|220
img3.jpg|540
img4.jpg|628
img5.jpg|342
```

than you can read the widths:

```
var widths = []; // Array to store read widths

$.get('folder1/galleryData.txt', function(data) {

     var line = data.split('\n');
     for(var i=0; i<line.length; i++){
         widths.push( line.split('|')[1] );
     }
     alert( widths ); // 340,220,540,628,342 

});
```

now the array widths will contain all the stacked images widths accessible like

```
widths[2]; // 540
```

You can now use a counter [n] and get the desired image upon some button click and animate your element -**backgroundPosition** with jQuery.

---

If every image's width is same... well, than the job is even simpler, you don't need to create noting, just stack all your images and do the **backgroundPosition** animation